# 3D Cosine Function for an HCP Lattice

Tags: vector-spaces, crystallography

I would like to construct a 3D cosine function, $f$, which is scaled to the range $f\in[-1,1]$, and which has maxima which coincide with the HCP lattice.

For example, here are the analogous 3D cosine functions for other lattices:

- **Simple Cubic (CUB)** $$f_\text{CUB}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\cos x + \cos y + \cos z \right)$$

[Plot of $f_\text{CUB}(2\pi x,2\pi y,2\pi z)>0.9$ for $\{x,y,z\}\in[-1,1]$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRbiN.jpg)

- **Body-centred Cubic (BCC)** $$f_\text{BCC}(x,y,z)=-1+\frac{2}{3}\left(\cos x \cos y + \cos y\cos z +\cos z \cos x \right)$$

[Plot of $f_\text{BCC}(2\pi x,2\pi y,2\pi z)>0.6$ for $\{x,y,z\}\in[-0.5,0.5]$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd4qq.jpg)

- **Face-centred Cubic (FCC)** $$f_\text{FCC}(x,y,z)=\cos x \cos y\cos z$$

[Plot of $f_\text{FCC}(2\pi x,2\pi y,2\pi z)>0.8$ for $\{x,y,z\}\in[-0.5,0.5]$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB9z0.jpg)

---

My closest guess at a general solution so far is something of the form: $$f_\text{lattice}(\mathbf{r})=A+B\sum_{i=1}^{\tilde{N}^\text{lattice}} \cos (2\mathbf{r}\cdot\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_i^\text{lattice}),$$

where $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$, $A$ and $B$ are offset and scaling constants, $\{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_i^\text{lattice}\}$ is the set of displacements from the origin to nearest neighbours in a cuboidal unit cell of the *reciprocal* lattice, and $\tilde{N}^\text{lattice}$ is the corresponding length of the set. However, this does not quite work for me... Any help, tips, or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :-)

---

2D EXAMPLE: **Simple Hexagonal Lattice (HEX)**

1) Write down all of the displacement vectors in one hexagon:

$$\mathbf{a}_1=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$
$$\mathbf{a}_2=\left(1,0\right)$$
$$\mathbf{a}_3=\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$
$$\mathbf{a}_4=\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$
$$\mathbf{a}_5=\left(-1,0\right)$$
$$\mathbf{a}_6=\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$

2) Plot these displacement vectors to verify that the hexagon has a lattice constant in the $x$-direction of $a_\text{x}=1$ and a lattice constant in the $y$-direction of $a_\text{y}=\sqrt{3}$.

[image: Plot of hexagon]

3) Construct the density and plot

$$f_\text{HEX}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^{6}\cos(2\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{a}_i),$$

where $\mathbf{r}=(x,y)$.

[image: Plot of HEX function]

Note that $a_\text{x}\to2\pi/a_\text{x}$ and $a_\text{y}\to2\pi/a_\text{y}$ since we recover the reciprocal lattice.

Comment: Do you have a solution for the simple hexagonal lattice, to begin with? More importantly, _which way_ would you like to have it? IMHO, it would look the best in fractional coordinates related to the lattice. If you insist on sticking to the orthogonal Cartesian system, it's possible anyway, but will look ugly.

Comment: Thank you for the response - I will have a go at the simple hexagonal lattice and update the question with this information. I don't mind if the solution is in fractional coordinates or Cartesians. I agree that fractional would look neater.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have added the 2D HEX example to the question, please let me know if this inspires any further ideas. Thank you!

Comment: It is not new ideas that we need; what you have here is basically a Fourier transform of electron density, a thing familiar to crystallographers. You cut it short and take a few terms that roughly reproduce the desired features. As soon as I have free time, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated!

Comment: Incidentally, I am in fact trying to calculate the real-space electron density for the HCP lattice, if that helps...

Comment: Fine! Than just do so. Imagine delta functions where the atoms should be, calculate the first ~20 Fourier terms, take 2 or 3 greatest of them and see what happens.

Comment: I have noticed for example on slide 8 on this link https://labs.uab.edu/walter/images/lecture4.pdf that I may need the form factor. The form factor is given on slide 13 of this http://ahrenkiel.sdsmt.edu/courses/Fall2016/NANO703/lectures/Ch16/TEM_Ch16_92.pdf Does the form factor come into this?

Comment: Forget the factors for a while. Your atoms are all identical anyway. Assume $f_i=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have tried today to Fourier transform the Dirac deltas, which gives me maxima in the correct positions, however not all are of the same magnitude and the maxima are ellipsoids rather than spheres. The points in my crystal should be indistinguishable and the electron densities around an atom should be spherically symmetric, so what I have done must be wrong. I am beginning to think that it's impossible :-(

Comment: What you have done is right. The maxima should all be round and identical if you take _infinitely many_ Fourier terms, or maybe **alternatively** (as I suggest) if you take just a few greatest terms and tweak with their coefficients a little.

Comment: Have you tried the points $\, (1,0,0),$
$\, (-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2, 0),$
$ \, (-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2, 0),$
$ \, (1/2, \sqrt{3}/6, \sqrt{6}/3),$
$ \, (-1/2, \sqrt{3}/6, \sqrt{6}/3),$
$ \, (0, \sqrt{3}/3, \sqrt{6}/3) \,?$

Comment: @IvanNeretin Apologies, although I'm sure that you have explained things well, I can't understand what you mean / get this to work. If are able to post an example or solution, I would be more than happy to accept it. Thank you for your help thus far, I definitely understand more about the problem now because of it, however I am simply unable to reach a solution :-(

Comment: @Somos Yes, I feel like I have tried everything possible combination of points now :-(

Comment: I got it. You won't get it look quite as nice as the rest, because _HCP is not a lattice in the first place_. It is merely a packing. Anyway, everything I said about the Fourier transforms still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer to this, so I'm posting it here in case other people find it helpful in the future. The solution is to take the superposition of the Fourier transforms of two offset hexagonal lattices, with an appropriate modulation along the z-axis. Something of the form

$$\begin{align}f_\text{hcp}(\mathbf{r})=A_\text{hcp}+\frac{B_\text{hcp}}{6}\Bigg[&\sum_{i=1}^{6}\cos(\mathbf{r}\cdot\tilde{\mathbf{r}}^\text{hcp}_i)\cos\left( \frac{3\pi}{\sqrt{6}a}z\right)\\
&+\sum_{i=1}^{6}\cos\left(\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\text{hcp}_7
   \right)\cdot\tilde{\mathbf{r}}^\text{hcp}_i\right)\cos\left( \frac{3\pi}{\sqrt{6}a}\left(z-\frac{\sqrt{6}a}{3}\right)\right)\Bigg],\end{align}$$

where $A_\text{hcp}$ if the offset constant, $B_\text{hcp}$ is the scaling constant, $\{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}^\text{hcp}_i\}$ is the set of displacement vectors to nearest neighbors in the reciprocal unit cell (where the first 6 form a hexagon in the $z=0$ plane), and $\mathbf{r}^\text{hcp}_7$ is the displacement to an atom in the neighboring plane for this AB stacking e.g. $\mathbf{r}^\text{hcp}_7=(1/2,\sqrt{3}/6,\sqrt{6}/3)$.

[[image: Plot of <span class=]$f_\text{hcp}(\mathbf{r})>0.9$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trnze.jpg)

This is a 3D cosine function, of an analogous form to the ones presented in the examples, which can be scaled to the range $f\in[-1,1]$, and which has maxima which coincide with the hcp lattice. Therefore, this precisely answers my original question.